# Double the "speed", double the frequency?

Tags: sound, acoustics, dsp-puzzle

Usually, when some sample is played-back at twice the rate it was recorded, the pitch of the recording sounds an octave higher.

For example: $g(t) = \sin(2 \pi f t)$ and $g(2t) = \sin(2 \pi f 2 t) \implies \sin(4 \pi ft)$. Where $f$ is a given frequency.

There are some strange "sample" cases however that when played back at twice their recording rate their pitch appears to...not have changed as expected. And some even stranger "sample" cases that when played back at twice their recording rate their pitch appears to be...lower!

How do these strange "sample" cases might "look like" (in terms of a mathematical description) and what are, broadly, the conditions that can lead to such cases?

**EDIT (hint 1):**

Variants of the technique of [pitch-shifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_shift) / [time stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_time-scale/pitch_modification) have been mentioned so far by more than one persons in relation to this question.

Pitch shifting is *not* the core of the question and the technique of pitch-shifting does not change the nature of the question.

As it was pointed out in one of the comments to this post and as a form of a hint: Yes, pitch shifting does alter the pitch of the "sample" but a) what sort of sample would sound almost identical to its unshifted version if it was passed through a $2 \times$ pitch shifter and b) what sort of sample would sound at a lower pitch if it was passed through a $2 \times$ pitch shifter. (the $2 \times$ here is just an example).

**EDIT (hint 2):**

Another two things that have appeared in responses so far are aliasing and some aspect of human hearing. In other words, "Maybe you have pitch shifted in such a way that the frequency jumps back on to itself" and also "Maybe you are taking advantage of some psychoacoustic phenomenon in which the frequency has changed but the perceived frequency does not"

Aliasing and the *limits* of human hearing **are** relevant to this question but are not absolute requirements for the "paradox" that is mentioned here to occur.

Comment: what you are describing is called *"pitch shifting"* and it can be considered the combination of two operations: *"time scaling"* and *"sample interpolation"* (or *"sample rate conversion"* even though we are not changing the sample rate).  the latter operation is mathematically well-defined.  it speeds up **and** raises the pitch together.  the *time scaling* operation is less well defined. it makes a sound longer (or shorter) *without* changing the pitch. so, to up-pitch a sound, first you have to time-scale it to be longer (and the same pitch), then apply SRC to shorten it to the original.

Comment: actually, what you are describing is just the *"time scaling"* operation.

Comment: It would be more clear if you add some instances of the sample cases you pointed out, as well as the way you playback with twice recording speed.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I don't know what to respond, that is correct. So, if it has to be framed under a pitch shifting framework: Are there any waveforms that if you pitch shifted them by 2 they would still sound very very very similar? MSM: Giving away the waveform is like giving away the puzzle and this is a "dsp-puzzle". Also, "twice the recording speed" or "twice as fast" is already defined in the post (?).

Comment: can also be the case of aliasing if the samples are skipped to match the playback speed

Comment: imagine that do you have a signal at 5000 Hz sampled at 44100 Hz, all OK 5000 Hz is inside the nyquist boundarie, now imagine resample this signal to 8000 Hz where go this frequency if we are out of the nyquist ? maybe are you talking about cases like this.

Comment: @A_A Oh, sorry I didn't get your message. Honestly, I am not so good in puzzles but I don't think if you pitch-shift a white noise it sounds much different. Also, a chirp signal seems to be a similar case.

Comment: @msm No worries. Faced with a puzzle, I have had [similar behaviour](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31899/how-do-you-simultaneously-undersample-and-oversample/32087#32087) in the past :) I think that your thinking process is drawing you near part (or maybe even the whole) of the answer.

Comment: Harmonic content that was outside the limits of human hearing before can become part of the perceived pitch after the frequency doubling.

Comment: What could cause this phenomena to occur is if the "speeding up" process was done by decimating: to play back twice as fast, while not changing the sample rate, we would skip every other sample. As long as the signal frequency was less than 1/4 the sampling rate, the signal frequency would double as expected. However, if the signal frequency was greater than 1/4 the sampling rate, alias frequencies would occur in the resulting Nyquist spectrum. For example, a signal at 0.3 fs would double to 0.6 fs after a decimate by 2, which would alias to 0.4 fs.

Comment: @nispio As with previous comments that are more of a statement, I don't know what to respond so I am going to go with "Yes, that is a correct observation". And yes, this does play a role in this phenomenon. Dan, this **could** be the basis or the start towards an answer, similarly to nispio's comment. Finally, many thanks to whoever responded so quickly to the last message about converting user Dan Boschen's response to a message.

Comment: @A_A Is the speedup you describe done by playing the samples faster while not changing the sample rate (meaning skipping samples as in my example such as to cause aliasing)?

Comment: @DanBoschen, it doesn't really matter **within reason**. See answers to this post. Thank you for the dsp-puzzle tag :)

Comment: @A_A Terrific! Thanks for this very interesting post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. White noise: sounds exactly the same if you play it back at double the speed
2. Stack up diminished fifth starting at a low enough fundamental (say 20 Hz). Play back at double speed: sounds exactly the same.
3. Stack octaves with equal amplitude starting with a low enough fundamental. Play back at twice the speed: sounds exactly the same
4. Detune the octaves slightly (say multipler of 2.05 starting at 20 Hz). Play back at double the speed: perceived pitch goes DOWN.

You get plenty more when fiddling with the harmonic structure. 
Code example for the last one:

```
%% make some disharmonic sounds
fs = 44100; % sample rate
q = 2.05; % harmonic multiplier
f0 = 20;  % fundamental
n = 10; % number of harmonics
duration = 2; % length of file at fs
nx = duration*fs;
t = (0:nx-1)'/fs; % time vector
x0 = sin(2*pi*f0*t); % fundamental
f1 = f0;
for i = 2:n  % add harmonics
  f1 = f1*q;
  x0 = x0+sin(2*pi*f1*t);
end

x0 = 0.5.*x0/max(abs(x0)); % normalize
% and play
sound(x0,fs); pause(duration);
sound(x0,2*fs);
```

Comment: Thank you Hilmar, that is indeed the "trick" :) I would suggest that in the presence of 2,3,4, we "drop" the white noise as a "trivial" case to this puzzle (but still a valid answer). I have only added a few more pieces of information in my response which might be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few pieces of background information that help in answering this question:

1. Geometric series and in particular geometric series as applying to music

   - A [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), $x_n$, is one where each successive term is generated by multiplying the previous term by some factor. For example: $x_{n+1} = a x_n$
   - Geometric series are everywhere in music, because [harmony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmony) is all about ratios between different tones (an interval) and the difference in auditory result they produce. Some are consonant, some are dissonant, some sound happy, some sound sad and so on.
   - On the keys of a piano, every successive tone results by multiplying the previous tone by a constant factor. [What factor is this?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelfth_root_of_two) Suppose two tones with frequencies $f_1, f_2$ where $f_2=2 f_1$. That would be some tone and the same tone **one octave above** it. The doubling of the frequency happens in 12 steps (e.g. $C, C \sharp, D, D\sharp, E, F, F\sharp, G, G\sharp, A, A\sharp, B$). This means that $a \cdot a \cdot a \cdot a \cdot a \cdot a \cdot a \cdot a \cdot a \cdot a \cdot a \cdot a = 2$ and therefore $a = \sqrt[12]{2}$ which is [approximately](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=twelfth+square+root+of+two) $1.0594\ldots$. It's the same story on the fretboard of a stringed instrument. The tones produced by plucking the string in two successive frets have a ratio of $a$.
   - So, if we start with an $A=440$ Hz, we know that $A \sharp = a A \approx 466.136$ Hz and 12 steps later $440 \cdot a^{12} =880$ Hz.
   - Why is it like this? Because it is a good compromise. Because otherwise, the piano would not have this distinct shape of two black keys, gap, three black keys, gap, two black keys but [a different pattern depending on the interval, chosen, to tune it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Hqm0dYKUx4). Which is what you can do with a [Sitar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitar) because its frets are movable.

Now, assuming a reference tone $A_{r}$, all successive tones are produced by $A_k = a^kA_{r}$ where $k$ is the number of **semitones** (the smallest difference in frequency between two successive keys on a piano or two successive frets on a guitar).

So, if we were to create a signal that contains a number of successive tones in octave intervals then, assuming that we start somewhere low enough, we would end up with something like 10,20,40,80,160,320,640,1280, 2560, 5120, 10240.

Playing this back, it sounds...sort of nice. "Speeding" this up at **twice the speed**, we get another signal which now contains tones: 20,40,80,160,320,640,1280, 2560, 5120, 10240, 20480.

Which is (almost) exactly the same as the one we started with. Of course, if we keep "pitch shifting", all we are achieving is pushing more and more tones past the limits of human hearing **or** within the region of suppression of the anti-imaging filter. In both cases, after a large number of shifts, the difference is audible because the signal does not contain as many harmonics.

These are called [Sheppard Tones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shepard_tone) and they sound [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzNzgsAE4F0).

In fact, Sheppard did specify that if you keep "feeding" the pitch shifting with low tones, then the perception is that the tones keep rising in pitch.

This is where DSP might step in and actually use the "aliasing". All that we have to do is remove the anti-imaging filter and make sure that we choose our $A_{r}$ in such a way that when the highest harmonic possible (given an $F_s$) is pitch shifted, it "folds" around the spectrum and ends up becoming $A_{r}$ again.

In such a "degenerate" case, we could keep pitch shifting the same number of harmonics again and again and again without the need to be "feeding" the shifter with "new" low frequencies.

For this to happen, given some $F_s$, we seek that geometric series which includes **both** $A_r, (F_s - A_r)$ and of course $\log_2\left(\frac{Fs-A_r}{A_r}\right) \in \mathbb{Z}$ and as large as possible.

This covers waveforms that do not "change" when pitch shifted by some even factor.

Pitch shifting and having the pitch go downwards is based on the same principle but is a bit more complex.

This can be done by that detuning mentioned by Hilmar in his response. The actual example that I had in mind when setting this dsp-puzzle, was that of the Weierstrass function.

The [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is:

$$ f(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a^k \cos(b^k \pi t)$$

Note here that the function is nothing more than a sum of cosines with an exponential amplitude profile. So, relatively low bass but lots of detail.

Things get out of hand with this function when $ab>1+\frac{3 \pi}{2}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}, b \in \{2l: l \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ (i.e. b is odd).

In that region, the function **is** continuous but **not** differentiable. Nowhere.

The informal way to understand why (or rather, the one that works for me (?)) is to consider $g(t)=t^2$ and try to find its [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) in two successive $t, t+\Delta t$, points. The derivative would be $\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{g(t + \Delta t) - g(t)}{\Delta t}$. Now, on $g$, that is not going to be a problem, because the more the limit "zooms in" (by successively reducing the $\Delta t$), the more the function tends to become like a line. After all, all we are doing is raising a number to a power. **But**, the more we are zooming in on the Weierstrass function ($f(t)$), the more detail it reveals and that derivative **never** settles to a value. **Never!**. Check this out:

[image: Visualisation of the Weierstrass function]

(Visualisation from [this link](https://www.math.washington.edu/~conroy/general/weierstrass/weier.htm))

And here is what happens, when you try to listen to that $f(t)$ at a different speed. Similarly to what happened with the Shepard tones:

What if we were to speed up $f(t)$ by a factor of $b$? Then:

$$ f(b t) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a^k \cos(b b^k \pi t) \implies \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a^k \cos(b^{k+1} \pi t)$$

And if we were to ignore the amplitude profile ($a^k$) and make the sum finite to some $K$, then:

$$ f(b t) = \sum_{k=2}^{K+1} \cos(b^k \pi t)$$

*Notice here how, $k+1$ was "absorbed" to show the similarity with the unshifted version*.

So, pitch shifting by $b$ seems to be leaving us more or less with the same function. Now, set $b = 2^{\frac{13}{12}}$ and pitch shift **by two**:

$$f_{before}(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \cos(2^{\frac{13}{12} k} \pi t)$$

$$\begin{matrix} f_{after}(2 t) = & \sum_{k=1}^{K} \cos(2 \cdot 2^{\frac{13}{12} k} \pi t) \implies \\ & \sum_{k=1}^{K} \cos(2^{\frac{12}{12}} \cdot 2^{\frac{13}{12} k} \pi t) \implies \\ & \sum_{k=1}^{K} \cos(2^{\frac{13}{12}-\frac{1}{12}} \cdot 2^{\frac{13}{12} k} \pi t) \implies \\ & \sum_{k=1}^{K} \cos(2^{(\frac{13}{12}-\frac{1}{12}) + \frac{13}{12} k} \pi t) \implies \\ & \sum_{k=1}^{K} \cos(2^{(k+1)\frac{13}{12}-\frac{1}{12}} \pi t) \implies \\ & \sum_{k=2}^{K+1} \cos(2^{k\frac{13}{12}-\frac{1}{12}} \pi t) \implies \\ & \sum_{k=2}^{K+1} \cos(2^{k\frac{13}{12}} 2^{-\frac{1}{12}} \pi t) \end{matrix}$$

So, the only difference between $f_{before}, f_{after}$ is that $2^{-\frac{1}{12}}$. That is, pitch shifting by two, introduces a "lower by 1 semitone" factor.

It gets freakier than this, for $b=2^{\frac{14}{12}}$ the lowering is a full tone and so on ($b=2^{\frac{q}{12}}$ with $q \in \left[13,14,15 \ldots 23\right]$) until $q=24$ where the pitch shifting now has come "full cycle".

And of course, to link it back to what Hilmar mentions, notice that $2^{\frac{13}{12}} \approx 2.1189\ldots$, that $0.1189\ldots$ "detuning" factor lands the components in such a way that the human ear choses to "latch" on the nearest tone (between $f_{before},f_{after}$) and thus perceived pitch goes down.

This covers waveforms for which the perceived pitch is lowered upon pitch shifting.

---

**A note on sources:**

- Long time ago, I read a book on Fractals and that is where I first saw the Weierstrass function. At the time of reading the book, I did not understand fully everything I read. But I was impressed and puzzled. That book was in a different language (than English) and in fact, it was a (bit of a sloppy) "copy-paste-translate" from various books. Very recently, I found the **original book** those authors had used and I couldn't believe my luck, I just grabed it. That original book is ["Fractals, Chaos, Power Laws: Minutes from an infinite paradise"](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486472043.html) by Manfred Schroeder. It is absolutely **E P I C**.
- Sheppard tones and the Weierstrass function are mentioned in pages 95-97 (in my edition).
- The part of the discussion on aliasing in this answer was added after quite a few people mentioned aliasing which motivated me to think about using it.
- The breakdown of how does the $2^{\frac{1}{12}}$ emerges is not mentioned in the book. I added it here because it is not exactly obvious. To this, I was helped by a friend (M.P.L) as initially I was trying to substitute $k+1$ when it really emerges on its own.
- The point about the Weierstrass function being continuous but not differentiable is the most difficult to grasp. Or, that has been very difficult for me. The mathematical proof, the way you go about pinpointing this fact, is not incomprehensible but it requires a lot of effort. Towards that goal, I found [Johan Thim's Masters thesis](http://epubl.ltu.se/1402-1617/2003/320/LTU-EX-03320-SE.pdf) incredibly useful. It contains a large number of such functions too, it's great.
- The initial part on geometric series and music is general knowledge from various sources and experiences, cannot exactly pinpoint their source but I have added as many links as I could.